# Cakephp Search from join table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Hello I am joining multiple tables in my query. I want to get the results based on the search keyword which I am checking on multiple tables.

Here is my code

```
public function getGigPostBasedOnSearch($keyword){
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(

            'contain' => array(
              'User','UserInfo', 'GigPostAndCategory.Category','Location','GigPostAndCalender'

            ),
              'conditions' => array(
                  'AND' => array( 
                      'GigPost.active' => 1,
               'OR' => array(

            array('GigPost.title LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            array('GigPost.description LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),
            array('Location.location_string LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'),


        )
)
                 //'OrderGigPost.request' => 0
            ),
            'order' => 'GigPost.gig_post_id DESC',

            'recursive' => 0
        ));
    }
```

The query works successfully and get me the results what I wanted. But in the same query I want to search in the **Category** table as well. But if I do so

```
array('Category.cat_name LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%')
```

I get an sql error which says it couldn't find column name.

Category table has two columns
`cat_id` and `cat_name`

and **GigPostAndCategory** has
`id`, `cat_id`,`gig_post_id` (because one `gigpost` can have multiple categories thats why I have made a separate table for that)

So I need help in getting a result based on category as well if searched keywords matches something in the Category

Answer (score 0):

When you 'contain' data, it often actually runs a separate query, then combines it together to return to you.

Because of this, you cannot run conditions against the contained tables (depending on some factors, but is best just assume you can't).

Instead, use JOINs.  This will ensure it's being pulled in the same query, and will give you access to the joined-table fields.

(Hint: You can look in DebugKit to see what queries are being run.  This will usually give you the clue you need as to why it's not working.)

Comment: thank you @dave... can you please write this query using join if possible, I am new to this and I know only this method